# Should I keep the SqlConnection open?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, unity-game-engine

In my Unity3D game the Player plays himself through short levels, which at the beginning take about 4 seconds. The goal is to get the best possible clear time in each level. I am currently saving these clear times locally, but I would like to upload them to an SQL Server, to be able to create a leaderboard for each level.

Since performing the `SqlConnection.Open()` command takes about 1-2 seconds, sometimes also 3, I was wondering whether I should keep a `static` connection always open, ready to execute any queries that I want to run.

Are there any unwanted and dangerous side-effects when doing it?

Edit: This is the code that I use for opening the SqlConnection.

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    DataSource = dataServer,
    UserID = userId,
    Password = password
};

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
connection.Open();
```

Comment: Why does opening the connection take 3 seconds?  Are you sure?  Ordinarily you would create and close connections as needed and let the connection pool do its thing.

Comment: @Amy I just checked again, the time is inconsistent, now it is between 1 and 2 seconds, previously it was at around 3. All I am doing is creating a new `SqlConnection` instance, with my credentials and then opening it.

Comment: Always use connection pooling in situations like this and dispose of open connections accordingly. You will most likely scale your application at some point or the other and that's when things will become a pain. Also, is it a local database? 3 seconds is a little excessive. If it's not a local db, try running the app on another device just to see if you aren't having local connection issues.

Comment: @Amy Alright I'll do that for now. If the user-experience is hassled too much by doing it like this, I'll look into it again, thanks for your help!

Comment: @BrandonMiller It's not local, it's located on a server. Thanks for the advice on connection pooling!

Comment: @yes I wanted to do that, unfortunately when I tried to connect to the MSSQL database, the browser tells me that the site currently cannot process the request.

Comment: @IanH. you *likely* made a mistake, but we can't be any more specific than that without being able to see the code.  SQL Server database connection strings are different from localdb strings.  Again, can't offer more without code.

Comment: If speed is important, maybe you should look into saving the results in the background while allowing the player to continue to play the next level.

Comment: @Amy I added the code.

Comment: @Jonny That's a great idea, I'll probably do that.

Comment: The big issue with having a static connection is that you then either a) have to make sure that your entire application is single-threaded (not ideal) or b) have to implement *locking* around use of the connection, which then means everything using it becomes serialized. *neither* of these is great from a performance perspective.

Comment: 3rd party clients shouldn't ever have direct access to a database. Have them connect via an API that you control (perhaps ASP.NET Web API or Nancy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll answer this question:

> Are there any unwanted and dangerous side-effects when doing it?

Assuming you keep this code in your Game (client) and the SQL Server is not client-side but in a server of yours located somewhere, a simple Client Reverse Engineer will be able to grab your credentials from your connection string and use them to gain Unauthorized access to your database. (NEVER trust the client)

With that being said, I would suggest you use a simple server-side technology (php,Socket App, Java servlet, etc..) along with the SQL that the client will send the information there and then to the database.

Example:

> 1) Client-> Posts Data -> PHP
>
> 2) PHP -> Connects -> SQL Database
>
> 3) PHP -> Inserts data -> SQL Database

Like this you can also retrieve the results of your ladder from the database by asking php (or whatever technology you are using) to send your data to the client.

Best wishes in your progress, and feel free to contact me for any additional information!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I ended up doing it with a PHP script and that works pretty well.